# How to access td from tr with id Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-selectors

My tr has id and two columns(tds) I want to change the second td html dinamically by doing this:

```
$("#value_"+ control_id+":nth-child(2)").html(type_id_name);
```

but it wipes all tds and it inserts the html in on column.

this is the table structure

```
<tr id="value_486">
  <td></td>
  <td></td>
<tr>
```

I tried different approaches as

```
$("#tableID tr#value_"+ control_id+":nth-child(2)").html(type_id_name);
```

but it doesnt work either.

Comment: You're adding `:nth-child(2)` to the main selector. That's not correct. It needs to descend from the `id`. Your selector is targeting a second `tr`, which doesn't exist.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to give a space or a `td` before the `:nth-child`. Space denotes a child or descendant selector:

```
$("#tableID tr#value_"+ control_id+" :nth-child(2)").html(type_id_name);
$("#tableID tr#value_"+ control_id+" td:nth-child(2)").html(type_id_name);
```

Your current one without the space:

```
$("#tableID tr#value_"+ control_id+":nth-child(2)").html(type_id_name);
```

Selects the second instance of the `<tr>`, which is not there!

```js
$(function () {
  var control_id = 486;
  var type_id_name = "Praveen";
  $("#tableID tr#value_"+ control_id+" :nth-child(2)").html(type_id_name);
  $("#tableID tr#value_"+ control_id+" td:nth-child(2)").html(type_id_name);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="tableID">
  <tr id="value_486">
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
  <tr>
</table>
```

And yeah, you don't need two `#id` selectors, when you are using `#id` to select. Your first style works.

Comment: Don't need the `table` or `tr` part of the selector.

Comment: @charlietfl See the last line... `:)`